# Hamstring pain while cycling

Tags: racing

I am getting serious pain in my hamstrings for the past couple of months while cycling. I warm up before I get on the bike and once I go back the road a bit the pain starts in both hamstrings. I got physio on lower back, a bike fit, foam rolls every night still no good. If I stand up while cycling I get relief until I sit down again and once I get off the bike no pain what so ever in my hamstrings, nothing feels tender. Could anyone help people are starting to think it is all in my head.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds likely that your seat is too low.  Your knee should be *almost* straight at the bottom of the stroke, while seated.

Comment: Do you ride with cleats or clips?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been fitted on you bike ? It might be that your saddle is not a the appropriate height. More so if you have lower bike pain while cycling.

Some websites will provide bike fit measurement based on your body measurements ([this one for example](http://www.competitivecyclist.com/Store/catalog/fitCalculatorBike.jsp)), you can start there. In general,  when the pedal is at 6 o'clock you want a slight bend in you knee (not fully extended, but not bent very much)

If that looks OK, I would check you pedaling technique, maybe you're doing something wrong there that creates pain.

Comment: Sitting on the saddle with the pedal at 6 o'clock and your heel (!) on the pedal, the leg should be almost straight. This said check for both sides and keep your hips level.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably worth looking for a potential change in your set-up which may have caused new stresses on your body. I have been suffering with chronic knee pain for the past 18 months, and it was mainly due to increase in intensity in too short of a period. This damaged my ligaments/tendons which continue to flare up through exercise. Is there anything that you may have changed such as a new saddle, new shoes etc?

It's always worth remembering that changing items likes shoes/cleats/saddles will have a knock-on effect with your height, even if it's minuscule. Unless the saddle is exactly the same model, it may sit higher or lower than the one previous and cause discomfort when riding.

You say you have had a bike fit, although from what I have heard these can be somewhat of a personal affair (vastly-differing opinions from shop to shop). I've never had a 'professional' bike fit, but managed to find my own comfort zone by adjusting my set-up in tiny amounts to see what differences it made. It could well be that your cleats (providing you have them) are positioned incorrectly, or alternatively your saddle is too low. Try small adjustments, even such as raising your saddle 5mm at a time and seeing if this helps.

I've learnt from experience after making some changes in terms of saddle and cleat choices prior to a 1400 miles cross-Europe cycle ride for charity. I needed to get it right in time, but not rush my set-up. I cannot emphasise how important small, gradual changes are as your body needs time to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

If you can - try riding on a static trainer (turbo).

Not to say your bike-fit is wrong ... but there are different levels of bike-fit and I have also seen examples of where a rider has gone in for a bike fit and measurements not work in the "real" world ie. on the road.

You will be able to make adjustments and gauge your comfort more safely. Also ride in and out of the saddle on the trainer as you would on the road too.